# Use static method inside instance method of the same class

Tags: java, static-methods, class-design, instance-methods

Let's say I have a class `Point`.
I want to give the user the tool to easily calculate the distance between 2 `Point`s, so I write the method:

```
static float distance (Point p1, Point p2)
```

Now, I also want to give the user the tool to directly calculate the distance between one `Point` he already instanciated and another `Point`:

```
float distance (Point p)
```

Is it a good idea to use the static method `distance(Point, Point)` inside the instance method `distance(Point)`? Something like:

```
float distance (Point p){
    return Point.distance(this, p);
}
```

This way I would reuse the code.

If it is a *bad* thing to do, why should I avoid this?

Comment: Seems good to me assuming it's necessary, but why do you feel it's necessary to have the second method? I don't really see a reason for it.

Comment: Do not provide the static methods. [They will only bring trouble when testing](https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html).

Comment: Provide the static methods.  It'd never be appropriate to mock or replace this sort of method; they're perfectly fine for testing.

Comment: @Gendarme I think some people may prefer to use static methods. I mean, I think it is more straight forward to have a method such as `distance(p1, p2)`, than having to write `p1.distance(p2)`. I know it is not a very good reason, but sometimes I feel like having to choose a *most important* object and use its method is a bit confusing. Or if not cunfusing a bit illogical. Probably it's just me tho :)

Comment: @Turing85 the article you linked brings for sure some good points, but I feel like your statement is a bit too strong. I think there are some situations where static methods are necessary for a good design. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Alternately you could put the static method in some utility class, `PointUtils`, so that there's less confusion between the two `distance` methods.

Comment: @markspace thank you! So, anyway, there is no problem in reusing the code in the static method in the istance method. Or vice versa, isn't it?

Comment: You don't need to use `Point` if it's in the same class. And @Turing85, the criticism of static methods does not apply to *pure functions*, such as the calculation of the distance between two points (assuming, of course, a fixed geometry). The linked article makes *absolutely no sense*; I have no idea how the author managed to think that you have to "instantiate" something to perform unit tests.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you for the answer! I put `Point.` just to be clear about the called method.

Comment: @Lapo I would say that *regardless of whether you use the internal static call*, you need to test the instance method independently--your test should be completely oblivious to the internal working of the method, just its contract.

Comment: @chrylis yes, this is true. So basically I reuse the code but not in a *logical* way. All I gain is the fact that I don't have to rewrite it. It is basically a copy-paste without CTRL+C and CTRL+V.

Comment: A static function is more suitable for functional programming style, an instance method more for object oriented style. Sometimes static methods can also help preventing NPEs. Instance methods help with method discovery via autocompletion. None is strictly better, but it would seem wise to pick one style and stick with it rather than providing multiple styles to pick from. That will become very tedious later on if you try to keep providing both styles for all methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people have debated about the general pros and cons of static methods with regard to testability, much of it I agree with. So I am not going to elaborate on that but just answer your question:

- Avoiding code duplication is a good idea, do it.
- I would do it just the other way around and call `p1.distance(p2)` from the static utility method and put the calculation logic into the non-static method if you insist in keeping the static method (I would eliminate it). I would say there is good reason to ask "hey, I have got this point p1, give me its distance to p2". I fail to see how this gets any easier with a static method. You need to provide two `Point` instances anyway, there is nothing you can do without instances, so why make it static in the first place?

Comment: plus one for your second point (stupid filter)

Comment: Thank you. And yes, probably the other way around is a better choice, since probably the instance method is the mosto important one, and the static method does the same thing in a way some people may prefer.